# Garbage (litter) filters - delete custom filters from the "more" dropdown

Tags: script, search

### About

Garbage (litter) filters is a userscript that allows users to delete custom filters from the top dropdown directly without scrolling down to the "custom filters" sidebar. Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411806/11407695), upon opening a `/questions` page, the script adds the deletion controls to each custom filter you have:

[image: custom filters removal preview]

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/garbage-filters/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/garbage-filters/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

The script *doesn't need* a userscript manager to work (but includes necessary headers).

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Opera | Firefox | Edge | IE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 93.0.4577.63 | ✔ 78.0.4093.184 | ✔ 92.0 | ✔ 93.0.961.38 | no |

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/garbage-filters/issues)

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/garbage-filters/blob/master/src/index.ts) written in TypeScript.

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/garbage-filters/pulls).